"In the northeast of downtown, there is an industrial park" => Does the park lie within or next to the downtown area?

"In the northeast of downtown, there is an industrial park"

=> Does the park lie within or next to the downtown area?
Is there anything changed if I use to instead of in?

In = within, to = past.

That means "City A is in the north of City B" is incorrect, isn't it? It should be "City A is to the north of City B". Do I understand it correctly?

Yes, you understand.  This is nonsense: "City A is in the north of City B".   North of, or to the north of.

But we would probably say "In the northeast section of the city". "Downtown" is highly unlikely there because industrial parks are usually located on the outskirts of a city,  not situated in the most desirable and expensive  "downtown" section.

@TimR - You're correct that it's nonsense while speaking casually, but formal legal designations of municipalities can be locally idiosyncratic. Where I live, we have two-tier municipalities, so you can say, "The City of Mississauga is in the south of the Regional Municipality of Peel."  We even have designated "cities" that are largely rural and contain unincorporated communities, so you can say, "The town of Lindsay is the largest population center in the City of Kawartha Lakes."

@CanadianYankee Yes ,we have townships in counties here, which is similar. But I wasn't referring to organizational subdvisions in general, involving a variety of terms, but specifically "city" in "city".

"in the northeast of downtown" is not idiomatic. The area northeast of downtown would be.

@TimR, "industrial parks are usually located on the outskirts of a city" - I suppose it depends on the city.  Boston's Seaport neighborhood was industrial and it boarders downtown (though separated by a narrow river).  In Seattle, the industrial SoDo neighborhood is just south of downtown, and the South Lake Union neighborhood, just to the north of downtown, was light industrial (until it was turned into Amazonia).  But the key thing is that the fact that these were industrial areas marked them as "not downtown".  So I agree that an "in the northeast of downtown" is very unlikely here.

@Juhasz By "outskirts" I don't mean ex-urban but well away from the downtown area of highrise office buildings and highrise residential buildings and
away from gentrified and even middle-class residential neighborhoods;  city real-estate is costly in all of those places. Consider this street view of Columbus Boulevard in Philadelphia, with the city skyline in the distance: https://maps.app.goo.gl/2AwfgAz8tEzqMAMf8


"In the northeast of downtown, there is an industrial park"

The park is within downtown, in the northeast section of it. "In" clearly indicates that downtown contains the park.

"To the northeast of downtown, there is an industrial park"

The park is outside of downtown, in a northeasterly direction. "To" indicates relative positioning.

Italy is in the south of Europe.
Africa is to the south of Europe.


Well and succinctly put.

You accept: in the northeast of downtown? I really do not...

@Lambie It's slightly clumsy, but I think acceptable. With other places than "downtown" it would be very acceptable.

Equivalent to the use of "To the..." would be to just say, "Northeast of downtown..." I think many native speakers would qualify the northeast with portion, section, or similar.
